# Отображение данных, полученных в ответ на json запрос

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый день. На запрос json, получаю такой ответ

```
data:Array[423]
[0 … 99]
0:Object
CityDescription:"Київ"
CityDescriptionRu:"Киев"
CityRef:"8d5a980d-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567626"
Delivery:Object
Description:"Відділення №1: вул. Пирогівський шлях, 135"
DescriptionRu:"Отделение №1: ул. Пироговский путь, 135"
Latitude:"50.353444000000000"
Longitude:"30.542863000000000"
Number:"1"
POSTerminal:"0"
Phone:"0-800-500-609"
PlaceMaxWeightAllowed:0
PostFinance:"1"
Reception:Object
Ref:"1ec09d88-e1c2-11e3-8c4a-0050568002cf"
Schedule:Object
SiteKey:"105"
TotalMaxWeightAllowed:0
TypeOfWarehouse:"9a68df70-0267-42a8-bb5c-37f427e36ee4"
__proto__:Object
```

Мне необходимо выпадающим списком вывести выпадающим списком "DescriptionRu" всех результатов(423)

Пробовал таким методом.

```js
 success: function(response)
        {
            
            console.log(response);
            
     var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);//parse JSON
            
            var output="<ul>";
            for (var i in json_obj) 
            {
                output+="<li>" + json_obj[i].DescriptionRu + "</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>";
            
            $('#content').html(output);
        }
```

Comment: Запускаете цикл по массиву, на каждой итерации куда-то, куда вам нужно, добавляете очередной элемент. На каком этапе у вас затруднения?

Comment: На этапе сбора этих данных и вывода на экран. находил примеры где перебирают массивы. по аналогии не вышло у меня ничего.

Comment: У вас ответ возвращается в **data**, но в своём коде вы нигде не используете это слово.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вы просто чуть ошиблись в структуре данных: судя по представленному вами выводу console.log, внутри response данные имеют структуру

```
{
    data: [
        {CityDescription:"Київ",.....,DescriptionRu:"....",..},
        {CityDescription:"Київ",.....,DescriptionRu:"....",..},
        {CityDescription:"Київ",.....,DescriptionRu:"....",..},
        ...
    ]
}
```

соответственно и перебирать нужно json_obj.data:

```
success: function(response)
{
    console.log(response);

    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) 
    {
        output+="<li>" + response.data[i].DescriptionRu + "</li>";
    }
    output+="</ul>";

    $('#content').html(output);
}
```

Comment: лучше обойтись без `for...in` с массивами

Comment: @Grundy да, вы правы, поправил. думал и так прокатит, ан нет, заметили )

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, ругается на строчку "var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);" 
VM759:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @WebMorda значит у вас response некорректный. выведите его в консоль и проверьте.

Comment: @WebMorda изменил код. попробуйте новый.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын. Благодарю. все отлично работает в div. Последний вопрос, как вывести это в элемент
<div class="inputs custom-attributes">
        <label>Склад Новой Почты:</label>
               <select name="address_attribute_1" id="address_attribute_1">
                      <option value="0">---</option>
               </select>
</div>

Comment: @WebMorda не понял. Тот код, который формируется выше, нужно добавить в приведенный блок? Или в select добавить набор options?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, списки полученные скриптом, вывести набором в options.

Comment: @WebMorda в цикле сформируйте поочереди все <option> и добавьте их потом в селект (в коде замените #content на id селекта). Для каждого option нужно указать value и текст.

Comment: Благодарю @ИванПшеницын. Все получилось.